# Sending email through Outlook on Windows 10 using VB6 error: runtime 287 - application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: outlook, vb6

We run an old Visual Basic 6 application on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

One of the functions is for sending outgoing email through the Outlook desktop client.

The same application that works on Windows 7 machines is not working on Windows 10 PC. No email is sent on Windows 10 PC.

```
Public Sub SendOlMail(Subject As String, attachment As String, Recipient As String, bodytext As String)

Const olMailItem = 0

Dim objOutl As Object
Dim objMailItem As Object

Set objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objMailItem.Recipients.Add Recipient
objMailItem.Subject = Subject
objMailItem.Body = bodytext
objMailItem.Attachments.Add attachment
objMailItem.Send

Set objMailItem = Nothing
Set objOutl = Nothing

End Sub
```

After removing `On Error Resume Next` I got the error message on Windows 10 PC.

> runtime 287 - application-defined or object-defined error

I found the error is on line `objMailItem.Recipients.Add Recipient` and looks like something missed in the Windows 10 PC.

Tried to run the app as administrator and still not working.

Comment: Is there anything in the Windows event logs which helps?

Comment: What have you tried so far? A good first step for debugging would be to remove the 'On Error Resume Next' line and run it again, so you can see what line is actually causing the error.

Comment: Thanks, will try that.

Comment: remove this line `On Error Resume Next` and then re-try. You will get the reason why its not working. Most likely you don't have Outlook installed on the machine.

Comment: Have you checked "Tools" -> "References" in the VBA window. Double check that the same library is marked in both windows 7/windows 10. (I still assume you have the same 32/64bit-Excel)

Comment: After take the On error resume next out, I got the error message on Windows 10 PC saying "runtime 287 - application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: I checked both platforms using the same version of outlook as well.

Comment: Which line raises that exception?

Comment: I can't tell, because I use the windows 7 as development machine and deploy the app on client PC which running on Windows 10

Comment: You could use "On Error GoTo Handler" to handle the error. For more information, you could refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement

Comment: I found the error start from the line "objMailItem.Recipients.Add Recipient" and look like something missed in the Windows 10 PC?

Comment: I read many different suggestions on the web, it seems may related to the security module of the outlook on Windows 10 and also someone mentioned about early/late binding in the code. Any suggestions, Thank!

Comment: No, tried to run the app as administrator and still not working.